# How to manage a simple configuration

Tags: haskell

My app needs a very simple configuration composed by a `basePath` initialized when the app starts, in this way:

```
data Conf = Conf {
    basePath :: FilePath
    genericValue :: Int
}

startApp :: IO ()
startApp = do
  hd <- getHomeDirectory
  let conf = conf (basePath = hd ++ "/some_dir/", genericValue = 10)
  -- start to pass around conf
```

To fetch the values I just use: `basePath conf` and `genericValue conf`.

Is there a better way to manage this and maybe avoiding to pass around this `conf` value across the functions? Around I can find suggestions like Reader Monad, but I cannot see the real advantage in it.

Comment: well as you mentioned it - the advantage of the reader monad would be that you don't have to pass `conf` around as a parameter ...

Answer (score 1):

Like @Carsten said, the advantage of the Reader monad is that you can avoid having to pass `conf` around! Instead of writing:

```
data Conf = Conf {
    basePath :: FilePath
    genericValue :: Int
}

somethingSimple :: Conf -> Foo
somethingSimple conf = ...

somethingElse :: Conf -> Bar
somethingElse conf = ...

somethingComplex :: Conf -> (Foo, Bar)
somethingComplex conf = (somethingSimple conf, somethingElse conf)
```

You'd write:

```
somethingSimple :: Reader Conf Foo
somethingSimple = do
  conf <- ask
  return ...

somethingElse :: Reader Conf Bar
somethingElse conf = do
  conf <- ask
  return ...

somethingComplex :: Reader Conf (Foo, Bar)
somethingComplex = do
  a <- somethingSimple
  b <- somethingElse
  return (a, b)
```

Thus eliminating the jugging-around of `conf` from the definition of `somethingComplex` entirely: you just define an action that reads *some* `Conf` value by combining other actions that read *some* `Conf` value. You only pass an actual `Conf` in once, namely to `runReader`!

Plus, you get to write cool stuff like:

```
somethingComplex' :: Reader Conf (Foo, Bar)
somethingComplex' = liftM2 (,) somethingSimple somethingElse
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I initialise the Reader Monad getting with the path at the beginning?

Comment: Just read/create your `Conf` value as you normally would, and then call `runReader somethingComplex yourConf` to get a `(Foo, Bar)` from it, here.

Comment: If I have to re-read/re-create my conf everytime I don't see the point using a reader monad. I wanna build the conf only once, as it might be expensive doing it (fetch info from a db, server, calculations etc).

Comment: It's only created once, `conf <- ask` retrieves it for use in each function.